# Any ideas on how to edit a browser to only have 2-3 tabs allowed and don't allow multiple instances of it

Tags: browser, configuration

In the Philippines, internet shops/ café owners are concerned with the internet connection due to the facts that isp's here offer an expensive rates when it comes to internet connection, Now the problem is how to offer customers to have a fair usage in the internet connection. Mainly users load facebook and youtube, Youtube is costly in bandwidth, And some of the users load tons of it. Shop owners are using Cache servers/ system to assist the connection but still youtube is a drag. Now, by any chance.. is there a way to edit a browser i.e chrome, firefox, etc to run only once and allow only 2-3 tabs? Depending on how the owner of the shop will allow tabs or atleast youtube will run only once in a browser?

It's complicated for me, and I have been searching all over. Any suggestion, opinion or help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mark my answer, which answered your question, for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

After a very quick google, I found [this plugin](http://www.chromestory.com/2010/04/how-to-limit-the-number-of-tabs-that-you-can-open-on-chrome/), that allows you to limit the amount of tabs that are open in Chrome.

Comment: the link is broken.. If this plug-in exists with an administrator capabilities, it would be a very good plug-in. I'm pretty sure if introduced in the community, some might find this helpful.

Comment: this plug-in I found in chrome does not have administrator privileges and also don't match my requirement of having the browser run only once. I mean like chrome running in one instance only. If two chromes are detected it won't allow, Hoping to find some add-ons or plug-ins in moz too. :(